# Text view overlapping when orientation with relative layout

Tags: android

the problem with this layout is that when i orientate, the text view overlaps with the buttons. I have tried frame layout, center gravity and many other options but to no avail. The picture below shows the problem. I would definitely need to use `RelativeLayout`.

[image] [image]

As you can see, when on landscape, the TEST textview is blocked. I would like to keep the **vertical center** position of the `TextView` on portrait mode and when landscape mode, position the **textview above the BUTTON1** such that it does not overlap. The Buttons have to be **remained at the bottom**.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="36sp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn1"
        android:text="button1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn3"
        android:text="button 2"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="button 3"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is your desired behaviour?

Comment: Do you need the buttons to be aligned at bottom?

Comment: @Mahmet Kologlu - I have added description on the behaviour on the question. Thank you for pointing that out,

Comment: @ValentinoS. Yes that is important to me,

Comment: What about using LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout?

Comment: @Alfred Woo As mentioned, i need to use relative layout

Comment: You can use a different layout file for landscape orientation, where the `TextView` is above `button1`

Comment: @A.A. If i were to do that, the text view would be at the top of the button but not at the Vertical center of the screen.

Comment: Sorry.. I missed that

Comment: @AlfredWoo No worries

Comment: As @A.A. says, it could be a solution that matches your requirements: "...and when landscape mode, position the textview above the BUTTON1"

Comment: Why would you need a RelativeLayout ? I think a ConstraintLayout would do the job

Comment: Do you need the text to be centered in the whole screen or the rest of the screen?

Comment: @A.A. rest of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `RelativeLayout` as a parent for your `TextView` above `btn1` with `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/activity_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn2"
        android:text="button1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn3"
        android:text="button 2"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="button 3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Another solution**

Add `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:layout_above="@+id/btn1"` to your `TextView`, and center the text in the `TextView` using `android:gravity="center"`

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_main"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="36sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn2"
        android:text="button1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn3"
        android:text="button 2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="button 3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Either solution should work fine for both portrait and landscape orientations

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="36sp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textview">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="button1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="button 2"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="button 3"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try this layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two layouts for your Activity. First in portrait mode and second in landscape. To do it you need to create an xml with the same name you have for your Activity, but append to it -land. After that this xml will be automatically used for your landscape mode. In that xml you can put whatever logic you want for your views. Do not forget to use the same view:id properties or you will have exceptions. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Insert your three buttons in a relative layout which should be align-parent-bottom. Then place your textview above of this relative layout. 
Hope it will work for you.

Comment: It would not, if i place above the linear layout, the text is not positioned in the center of the screen but just the top of the button

Comment: No, that will not align the TextView center with respect to phone height

Comment: It would help if i see some form of example on what your are hinting. I dont know how should i implement that

Comment: ok but if you place testview at center of screen, again in smaller devices it will not work